# Why do I have stray bullet from <?php wp_list_categories>?

Tags: categories, css

On this page, I have a stray bullet at the right of the side search jobs navigation? Why is this? It may that I am missing something simple. I just have been at for awhile. http://shs.merms.info/2010/12/30/shs-team-celebrates-successful-quarter/

```
<ul>
    <li><?php wp_list_categories('title_li=<strong>Categories</strong><br />'); ?></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

`wp_list_categories()` starts its output with a `<li>`, so you don't have to write it yourself. What you get (check your source code) is:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <li class="categories"><strong>Categories</strong>
        <ul>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a href="http://shs.merms.info/category/article/" title="View all posts filed under Article">Article</a></li> 
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a href="http://shs.merms.info/category/awards/" title="View all posts filed under Awards">Awards</a></li>
            <!-- More items -->
        </ul>
    </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`<li><li>` is invalid and gets converted to `<li></li><li>`, giving you an extra bullet. You should remove the `<li>...</li>` around your call to `wp_list_categories()`.